# How to make a POST with ajax just like the form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm trying to send a POST request to my python (Google App Engine) server using Ajax just the way we do from a form submit, but it's not working.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>apple</button>
  <form method="POST" action="/">
  <input name="url" value="value1" id="urlimg">
  <br>
  <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="FIND OUT" id="submit_button">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('button').click(function() {
          $.post('/', { url: 'value1'});
       });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my python code:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
import urllib2 as urllib

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                           autoescape = True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self,*a,**kw):
        self.response.write(*a,**kw)

    def render_str(self,template,**params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self,template,**kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template,**kw))

class MainHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('image.html')
    def post(self):
        url = self.request.get('url')
        self.response.write(url + ' is your url')
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: what does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: when i submit the above form it show the input on the screen,but when i send post using the script it doesn't do anything.

Comment: But what do you want it to do?

Comment: Try: `<button id="button">apple</button>`

Comment: i want to send a post request the same we do using a form.

Comment: From what I can see the post request should go just fine. But, there is no callback function on the `$.post` request in the client side code. What it means is that you have not specified what to do after the post request go through successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the response as a JSON object:

```
class MainHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('image.html')
    def post(self):
        import json

        url = self.request.get('url')

        response_dict = {
            'message': 'Yay, I did it!', 
            'url': url + ' is your url',
        } 

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response_dict))
```

And handle the response in your template thusly:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("/", { url: $('#urlimg').val()}, function(data, status){
        alert("message: " + data.message + "\nURL: " + data.url + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```